# I want to take url from page's view page source

Tags: javascript, php, regex, web, web-scraping

For example this url

```
https://in.pinterest.com/pin/695524736192250687/
```

from its page source want to take

```
<img alt=" " class="hCL kVc L4E MIw" importance="auto" loading="auto" src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a8/7f/22/a87f2200109b01fc7a74b6106cb76f7b.jpg"/>
```

echo this from its page source:

```
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a8/7f/22/a87f2200109b01fc7a74b6106cb76f7b.jpg
```

on

```
https://youtubethumbnaildownload.online
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to **scrape** the data from the source code and then look for the `class` and `img` tags or whatever else you need to do.

> A simple PHP HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+, supports invalid HTML, and provides a very easy way to find, extract and modify the HTML elements of the dom. jquery like syntax allow sophisticated finding methods for locating the elements you care about.

Answer (score -1):

You can store this url into session variable for the current page and then retrieve this session on another page where you want that url.

like :

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $url; // store value/url in session 
$uel= $_SESSION['url']; //retrieve session value on another page
```

Make sure that you need to strat your session first.

```
session_start();
```